# Can HASL finish be used for castellated pads?

Tags: pcb, pcb-assembly

I am designing a PCB that uses castellated edges to connect to the parent board. I would like to use HASL finish to save on costs for prototyping, but I am concerned that the non-planar surfaces of the module may pose assembly issues. Is it common at all to use HASL for castellated boards, or do I need ENIG to ensure successful assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HASL works fine for PTH, even large holes, I see no reason for it to not work with castelation.

It does somewhat bind you to a solder chemistry, (lead or lead-free) and also has a shorter shelf-life than ENIG